# How to Set the State of a UISwitch to off or Left when view appears

Tags: xcode, swift

When the view loads I need the "SwitchMain" to look like its off so the switch is to the left and not green and to the right. Thanks

Code:

```
   class SoundController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var SwitchMain: UISwitch!

  override func viewDidLoad()  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("Did make it to View")

   }
   }
```

Comment: Question is not clear can you describe more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fairly simple:

```
override func viewDidLoad()  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("Did make it to View")

    self.SwitchMain.on = false
}
```

*Note*: For this to work, the `IBOutlet` should be connected to the `UISwitch` element in the interface.